# Интерфейсы. Условие реализации интерфейса классом

Tags: java, ооп, интерфейс, класс

Изучаю java, возник следующий вопрос по интерфейсам.
Для использования статического метода sort() из класса Arrays для объектов некого класса, должно соблюдаться условие, что данный класс реализует интерфейс Comparable, а именно метод compareTo(Object o).

Я нигде так и не смог найти толкового объяснения данному явлению. Буду крайне признателен, если кто-то объяснит почему надо реализовать интерфейс, чтобы воспользоваться методом.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что код сортировки должен как-то сравнивать объекты между собой, чтобы их отсортировать. Но сам алгоритм сравнения он не содержит (ведь одно дело сравнивать числа, другое - строки, третье - сложные структуры - всего не предусмотришь). Вместо этого, он предлагает внешнему коду передать этот алгоритм сравнения в виде объекта.

Но объекты могут быть какими угодно. А коду сортировки нужен только объект которым этот код умеет пользоваться. Поэтому он сообщает внешнему миру, что он умеет пользоваться только объектами, которые реализуют интерфейс `Comparable`.

Таким образом, код сортировки уверен, что получив такой объект, у него будет доступный публичный метод `compareTo`, которым код сортировки сможет воспользоваться для сравнения двух элементов сортируемого множества.

Comment: "Поэтому он сообщает внешнему миру, что он умеет пользоваться только объектами, которые реализуют интерфейс Comparable".
А как с синтаксической точки зрения проискодит эта привязка? Как задать условие реализации интерфейса для пользования этим кодом?

Comment: Через параметр метода, который указывает тип интерфейса, а значит принимает всё, что имплементирует этот интерфейс. Компилятор не даст передать в этот метод что-то, что не реализует указанный интерфейс. Это один из примеров полиморфизма.